# Why does Java StringLatin1.regionMatchesCI method perform toUpperCase() and than toLowerCase() when comparing chars?

Tags: java, equals

I was looking into `String.euqalsIgnoreCase` method and found that at the end it invokes `StringLatin1.regionMatchesCI` method.

However, the code of this method seems strange to me, here it is:

```
public static boolean regionMatchesCI(byte[] value, int toffset,
                                      byte[] other, int ooffset, int len) {
    int last = toffset + len;
    while (toffset < last) {
        char c1 = (char)(value[toffset++] & 0xff);
        char c2 = (char)(other[ooffset++] & 0xff);
        if (c1 == c2) {
            continue;
        }
        char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
        char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
        if (u1 == u2) {
            continue;
        }
        if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why check the upperCase and than lowerCase? Wouldn't the lower cases always fail in case the upper check doesn't match? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the source code I found (somewhere on google) for this function I have additional explanation:

```
        // try converting both characters to uppercase.
        // If the results match, then the comparison scan should
        // continue.
        char u1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1);
        char u2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2);
        if (u1 == u2) {
            continue;
        }
        // Unfortunately, conversion to uppercase does not work properly
        // for the Georgian alphabet, which has strange rules about case
        // conversion.  So we need to make one last check before
        // exiting.
        if (Character.toLowerCase(u1) == Character.toLowerCase(u2)) {
            continue;
        }
```

So it looks like some workarounds. On github you might find even more different implementations of this function.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Why than don't use lowerCase in the first place? Or the problem will be the same?

Comment: I dont know, but it might be important that the toLowerCase is made on u1 and u2 which are the upper case characters after previous toUpperCase operation. There should be somewhere a test case which verifies this `Georgian alphabet` issue.

Comment: @DmitriyDumanskiy See also: [The Infamous Turkish Locale Bug](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug)